# How to print two 1-D arrays next to on another in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on an assignment that involves writing a program in C that reads data from a .txt file and saving it in a 2-D array. I then calculate the averages of each row and column. I have the program written and it works fine but I would like to be able to have the output display the row averages and column averages side by side instead of just all in a single row going down the screen.

```c
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    j = 0;
    if (j < ncols)
    {
        printf("\nAverage for row %i", i);
        fprintf(fileavg, "\nAverage for row %i", i);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n %5.2lf\t", row_avg[i]);
    fprintf(fileavg, "\n %5.2lf\t", row_avg[i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
{
    i = 0;
    if (i < nrows)
    {
        printf("\nAverage for column %i", j);
        fprintf(fileavg, "\nAverage for column %i", j);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n %5.2lf\t", col_avg[j]);
    fprintf(fileavg, "\n %5.2lf\t", col_avg[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two pieces of text to be side by side, you should print them without a new line in between.  This can get pretty annoying with formatting, especially because the averages are unlikely to be the same number of digits.

Do you mean you want the order to go `row_avg[i]`, `col_avg[i]`, `row_avg[i+1]`, `col_avg[i+1]`, etc?

If so, here's how to do that.  The key is incrementing `i` and `j` *in the same loop*.  What you're doing is initializing `j` to `0` for each row `i`.

```
j=0; 
for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
{ 
    printf("\nAverage for row %i", i); 
    printf("\n %5.2lf", row_avg[i]); 
    fprintf(fileavg, "\nAverage for row %i", i);
    fprintf(fileavg, "\n %5.2lf", row_avg[i]);
    if (j < ncols) {
        printf("\nAverage for column %i", j);  
        printf("\n %5.2lf", col_avg[j]); 
        fprintf(fileavg, "\nAverage for column %i", j); 
        fprintf(fileavg, "\n %5.2lf", col_avg[j]); 
    }
    jj++

}
```

I think this is the basic structure you want.  If `nrows == ncols`, you don't have to worry about that `j < ncols` clause, and you can just print it out.

You can rearrange the print statements, including and excluding `\n` and `\t` to get the result that you like.  Also, in general, it's better to put your new lines *after* your line rather than before, but I'm not sure how codified that is.